# Mono compile on Solaris

Tags: c#, mono, mutex, solaris, sparc

I am trying to compile mono on Solaris 10. I have tried a lot of version from 2.11.4 to the todays latest 5.xx versions. But I have the failure all the time.

I am using *Sun-Fire-v240* hardware which has SPARC processor.
 Also, OS version is *Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC*

The problem that i am getting is this:

```
checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE... no
configure: error: Posix system lacks support for recursive mutexes
```

is there a way to compile mono for Solaris, I have been searching this problem for a while, but I had no working result for my case. I am not that good over UNIX systems, so I guess i am missing something...

Thank you.
Best Regards, Orhan.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a two-year-old Mono bug, [Bug 31999 - C99 and XPG5 don't match on Solaris 10+](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31999):

> ```
> checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE... no configure: error: Posix
> system lacks support for recursive mutexes
> ```

which is incorrect.  In config.log I find

> ```
> configure:22190: checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE
> configure:22206: gcc -m64 -R/vol/gnu/lib/amd64 -c -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-
> aliasing -fwrapv -DMONO_DLL_EXPORT -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -g -Wall -Wunuse
> d -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-pro
> totypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wno-cast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wno-swi
> tch -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-unused-value -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs -Wno-char-subscr
> ipts -I/vol/mono-4.0/include -DGC_SOLARIS_THREADS -DGC_SOLARIS_PTHREADS -D_REENT
> RANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DUSE_MMAP -DUSE_MUNMAP -DPLATFORM_SOLARIS -g -W
> all -Wunused -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes  -W
> missing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wno-cast-qual -Wwrite-strin
> gs -Wno-switch -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-unused-value -DLARGE_CONFIG  -D_XOPEN_SOURC
> E=500 -D__EXTENSIONS__ -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1 conftest.c >&5
>
> In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:8:0,
>                  from conftest.c:106:
> /vol/gcc-4.8/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.8.0/include-fixed/sys/feature_test
> s.h:363:2:
> error: #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open
> applications and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
> #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
>   ^
> conftest.c:108:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
>   ^
> conftest.c:108:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
>  main ()
>  ^
> configure:22206: $? = 1
> configure: failed program was:
> [...]
> configure:22213: result: no
> configure:22215: error: Posix system lacks support for recursive mutexes
> ```

This error is an artefact of the fact that configure.ac has

```
  CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500"
```

while on Solaris 10 and up C99 can only be used with XPG6/_XOPEN_SOURCE=600. Completely omitting the _XOPEN_SOURCE definition isn't an option since without it, `<sys/socket.h>` struct msghdr lacks the msg_flags member.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you, this did not worked. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: @OrhanT What do you see if you run `grep PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE /usr/include/*`?

Comment: it prints `/usr/include/pthread.h:#define  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE         0x4`

Comment: Based on the same error from GnuTLS on Solaris 11.3, I believe you need to `CFLAGS+=("-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -std=c99")` and `CXXFLAGS+=("-std=c++03")`. In the case of GnuTLS the project was using `-std=gnu99` for C files.